# The output is number that signifies the smallest number of hops/jumps

Tags: java, android

Create an app that receives input from the terminal console/UI and gives the output on the console/UI.

1st input - A list of 3 letter words. 
2nd input - One word from the above list. 
3rd input - Another word from the list.

The output is number that signifies the smallest number of hops/jumps that one can make from the 2nd input to reach the 3rd input. Every hop/jump has the following rules :
1.  In every hop/jump you can change only one character at a time. 
2.  The resulting word should be in the list. 
Example :

1st Input = ["cat","cii","sim","xim","yep","syd","pol","sit","sii","mat","sat","cit"]
2nd Input = "cat"
3rd Input = "sii"

Hops/Jumps path :

"cat" -> "cit" -> "cii" -> "sii"

Output - 4

Comment: We'll help you with your homework if you come close and need a push over the edge.  We aren't going to do it for you.

Comment: Hi gabe sechan thanks for response

Answer (score 1):

You can solved this problem using [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

You just need to transform each input string become a Node.

Then for every pair of Node, you connect with the Edge if they only differ exactly 1 character.

Then you can run your BFS Algorithm to find the shortest path.